# lib/pq connects but query fails with bad connection

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 from Digital Ocean. I've installed Postgres by calling `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`. I installed the Postgres driver by calling `go get github.com/lib/pq`.

I made an Ubuntu user called `foo`. Then, I used `createuser --interactive` to create a Postgres role called `foo` with only the attribute `Create DB`. Next, I create a new database by calling `createdb foo`. Finally, I create a new table with `CREATE TABLE`. Oh, and I've added `export PGHOST=/var/run/postgresql` to my `.bashrc` file.

Then, I wrote the following file at `/home/foo/go/src/dbtest.go`.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    connInfo := "username=foo dbname=foo host=/var/run/postgresql sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM bar")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err) // Code fails here.
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    fmt.Println(rows)
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the call to `sql.Open` doesn't return an error, but when I call `db.Query` I get `driver: bad connection`. I can use the Postgres interpreter just fine as user `foo`, but when I try a query from Go it fails. I suspect this might be a permission issue.

Comment: without knowing go, but your host information seems a bit odd. shouldn't it be localhost? or the hostname of your DB server?

Comment: Also, from the documentation: `Open may just validate its arguments without creating a connection to the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping.`

Comment: In addition, you should verify that PostgreSQL is indeed listening on a Unix socket (as indicated by `/var/run/postgresql`). Checking the PostgreSQL logs for errors will also show if your application is even hitting the database in the first place, or whether there is a permissions/authentication issue preventing this.

Comment: OH! The error logs say `unrecognized configuration parameter "username"`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string parameter should be `user=foo`, not `username=foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, the reason was context was cancelled in another flow.